# Is there a word for a briefer?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say, if the president went to a party and doesn't remember the name of the person he's talking to, his assistant whispers into his ear: "That's the prime minister of the UK, Mr. President, she did this and this and this." Is there a name for that person?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Aide](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Aide)

> 1. an assistant or helper, esp. a confidential one.

Of course, it’s just another word for assistant but in this context, it has the nice effect of bringing to mind the idiom [aide memoire](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Aide+Memoire).

Answer (score 3):

**attaché**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/attache)

> a person officially assigned to the staff of a diplomatic mission to
>   serve in a particular capacity: a cultural attaché; a military attaché

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "advisor" is a good word. Especially if he's whispering in his ear or telling him what to do.

A person who gives advice in a particular field.
‘the military adviser to the President’
[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adviser)

Also spelled adviser.

I found [Senior Advisor to the President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senior_Advisor_to_the_President_of_the_United_States)

> Advisor to the President: "Don't say $h!thole countries. Don't say
>   $h!thole countries."
>  Trump: “Why are we having all these people
>   from $h!thole countries come here?”

Answer (score 1):

> **Minder** (slang) an aide to someone in public life, esp a politician or political candidate, who keeps control of press and public relations

[source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/minder?s=t)

To me, at least, *minder* has at least some connotation that the person being minded would not be able to take care of themselves.

I'm also reminded of the *flappers* in *Gulliver's Travels* who were employed to waggle their employer's lips and eyes to save them effort when dealing with other people.